# How to create a custom clock for use in std::chrono functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I have some arbitrary epoch, like July 13, 1988. Essentially I want to measure the time relative to this. I was thinking of writing a custom clock class, so that I could write code like this:

```
using std::chrono;
time_point<My_Clock> tp;
std::cout << duration_cast<seconds>(tp.time_since_epoch()).count() << std::endl;
```

Is this possible? If not, what's the cleanest way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'll bet the standard has requirements listed.

Comment: `time_point` accepts `Clock` as a template, which is a concept. You could just write your own class that satisfies the requirements imposed by that particular concept. But don't take my word for it all, I'm just thinking out loud.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I looked into the source for system_clock for an example of this but I didn't get very far. I don't see where the actual epoch is specified. I think it's system dependent. Where would I find documentation for how to do something like that?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The hard part of writing this custom clock is figuring out how to write its `now()` function.  In the example below I base the `now()` off of `system_clock`'s `now()`.  First I do some detective work to discover that my `system_clock` has an epoch of New Years 1970, neglecting [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_seconds).  This is known as [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  As it turns out, every implementation I'm aware of (and I think I've checked them all) have this very same epoch (but this is unspecified by the C++11 standard).

Next I compute that 1988-07-13 is 6768 days after 1970-01-01.  Using these two facts, the rest is easy:

```
#include <chrono>

struct My_Clock
{
    typedef std::chrono::seconds              duration;
    typedef duration::rep                     rep;
    typedef duration::period                  period;
    typedef std::chrono::time_point<My_Clock> time_point;
    static const bool is_steady =             false;

    static time_point now() noexcept
    {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        return time_point
          (
            duration_cast<duration>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()) -
            hours(6768*24)
          );
    }
};
```

`MyClock` needs nested typedefs to describe its `duration`, `rep`, `period`, and `time_point`.  Based on your question, I've chosen `seconds` as the `duration`, but you can choose anything you want.

For the `now()` function I just call the `system_clock::now()` and subtract off the epoch in units of seconds.  I got just a little clever with this computation by writing everything in terms of `MyClock::duration` so that I can more easily change `duration`.  Note that I was able to subtract off the epoch in terms of `hours`, which implicitly converts to `duration` (which is `seconds`).  Alternatively I could have built myself a custom `duration` of days:

```
typedef std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio_multiply<std::chrono::hours::period,
                                                       std::ratio<24>>> days;
```

And then the return of `now()` could have been written:

```
        return time_point
          (
            duration_cast<duration>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()) -
            days(6768)
          );
```

At any rate, now you can use this like:

```
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    time_point<My_Clock> tp = My_Clock::now();
    std::cout << tp.time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';
}
```

Which for me just printed out:

```
786664963
```

Which demonstrates that today (2013-06-16) is approximately 24.9 years after 1988-07-13.

### Update for C++20

In C++20 you can use the updated `<chrono>` calendrical services to eliminate the "magic number" from the implementation:

```
#include <chrono>

struct My_Clock
{
    typedef std::chrono::seconds              duration;
    typedef duration::rep                     rep;
    typedef duration::period                  period;
    typedef std::chrono::time_point<My_Clock> time_point;
    static const bool is_steady =             false;

    static time_point now() noexcept
    {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        return time_point
          {
            duration_cast<duration>(system_clock::now() - sys_days{July/13/1988})
          };
    }
};
```

There is no run-time expense for this convenience.  The sub-expression `sys_days{July/13/1988}` is optimized at compile-time into a count of days since the `system_clock` epoch, and then further converted to `system_clock::duration` (still at compile-time) before being subtracted from `system_clock::now()`.

Comment: As of c++ 20, the standard specifies Unix epoch (1970-01-01) for system_clock.