# boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer custom clock

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, c++-chrono

I would like to create a custom clock that can be set manually and used with a `boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer`

I have tried the following:

```
class my_clock {
public:
    using duration = std::chrono::nanoseconds;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>;
    static time_point now() {
       return n;
    }
    static void set_now(time_point now) {
        n = now;
    }
private:
    static time_point n;

};
my_clock::time_point my_clock::n = my_clock::time_point();
```

Then use it in the following manner:

```
boost::asio::io_context ctx;
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
my_clock::set_now(now);
auto next_expire = now + std::chrono::milliseconds(10);
boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<my_clock> ctimer(ctx);
ctimer.expires_at(next_expire);

int count = 0;
ctimer.async_wait([&](const boost::asio::error_code& ec) {
    count++;
});
ctx.run_one();
// count == 0
my_clock::set_now(next_expire + std::chrono::seconds(1));
ctx.run();
// count == 1, except it's NOT
```

Any suggestions on how to inject a custom clock into the `basic_waitiable_timer` in this fashion?

Answer (score 2):

With the help of @sergiopm's response, the following is a working solution:

```
class my_clock {
public:
    using duration = std::chrono::nanoseconds;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<my_clock>;
    using rep = duration::rep;
    using period = duration::period;
    static constexpr bool is_steady = false;

    static time_point now() noexcept {
       return n;
    }
    static void set_now(time_point now) {
        n = now;
    }
private:
    static time_point n;
};
```

You then need to override the wait traits of the waitable_timer so that it won't wait on the wall clock when polling the io context:

```
struct wait_traits
{
  static typename my_clock::duration to_wait_duration(
      const typename my_clock::duration& d)
  {
        return std::chrono::nanoseconds(0);
  }
};
```

Then exercise as follows:

```
asio::io_context ctx;
auto now = my_clock::time_point(my_clock::duration(10));
my_clock::set_now(now);
asio::basic_waitable_timer<my_clock, wait_traits> ctimer(ctx);
auto next_expire = now + std::chrono::milliseconds(10);
ctimer.expires_at(next_expire);
ctimer.async_wait([&](const asio::error_code& ec) {
    future_period_count++;
    std::cout << "THIS HAPPENED" << std::endl;
});
ctx.poll_one();
REQUIRE(future_period_count == 0);
my_clock::set_now(next_expire + std::chrono::seconds(1));
ctx.run_one();
REQUIRE(future_period_count == 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as your clock satisfies the [TrivialClock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialClock) requirements, you should be able to use it with [basic_waitiable_timer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer.html).
A couple of examples:

- [How to create a custom clock for use in std::chrono functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533156/how-to-create-a-custom-clock-for-use-in-stdchrono-functions)
- https://github.com/korfuri/fake_clock