# What clock does the Visual Studio 2017 CRT implementation of std::chrono::system_time use?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

The comments in the chrono header just says

```
// wraps GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime/GetSystemTimeAsFileTime
```

But which does it actually use (i.e. what precision can I expect)? The implementation calls `_Xtime_get_ticks`, but that function is opaque.

Comment: "*what precision can I expect*" You can ask the clock what precision it provides with `system_clock::period`.

Comment: No not opaque... see the source in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\...\Source

Comment: The documentation for GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime says you can expect less than 1 microsecond of precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CRT calls `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` when available and `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` otherwise.
`GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` gives you the [highest possible level of precision (<1us)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtimepreciseasfiletime).

Sometime during the initialization of the runtime, a function named `initialize_pointers` gets called which basically does the following (decompiled and simplified):

```
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandleW(L"kernel32.dll");

__encodedKERNEL32Functions[0] = (void *)GetProcAddress(hModule, "FlsAlloc");
__encodedKERNEL32Functions[1] = (void *)GetProcAddress(hModule, "FlsFree");
__encodedKERNEL32Functions[2] = (void *)GetProcAddress(hModule, "FlsGetValue");
__encodedKERNEL32Functions[3] = (void *)GetProcAddress(hModule, "FlsSetValue");

...


__encodedKERNEL32Functions[24] = (void *)GetProcAddress(hModule, "GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime");

...
```

On a system with Windows 8 or newer `__encodedKERNEL32Functions[24]` will be non-zero.

It then comes down to this:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::now()
-> _Xtime_get_ticks
   -> __crtGetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(FILETIME *)

void __crtGetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(FILETIME *lpSystemTimeAsFileTime)
{
    void (*f)(FILETIME *) = (void (*)(FILETIME *))__encodedKERNEL32Functions[24];
    if (f)                         // if GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime exists
        f(lpSystemTimeAsFileTime); // call it
    else
        GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(lpSystemTimeAsFileTime);
}
```

At least this is (approximately) how it's implemented in the **14.16.27024.1** version of **msvcp140.dll** and **msvcp140d.dll**.

All of this is of course undocumented and subject to change.

If you need to use `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` you should [write your own clock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16533156/2682312) and not rely on implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

```
long long _Xtime_get_ticks()
{   /* get system time in 100-nanosecond intervals since the epoch */
FILETIME ft;
__crtGetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(&ft);
return ((((long long)ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32)
    + (long long)ft.dwLowDateTime - EPOCH);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's do some research here. First, let's find "`_Xtime_get_ticks`" in the Visual C++ runtime library:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>dumpbin /exports msvcp140.dll|findstr /I "Xtime"
       1483  5CA 0000B5D0 _Xtime_diff_to_millis
       1484  5CB 0000B610 _Xtime_diff_to_millis2
       1485  5CC 0000B650 _Xtime_get_ticks
       1515  5EA 0000B730 xtime_get
```

Then, I use `dumpbin /disasm msvcp140.dll` with `msvcp140.i386.pdb` file in the same directory:

```
__Xtime_get_ticks:
  1000B650: ... boilerplate ...
  1000B659: E8 22 50 02 00     call        ___crtGetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime
```

There is no `call` instruction for `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` anywhere in this disassembled function, so it seems clear that `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` is indeed the only function that is called for the underlying implementation.

Comment: Why jump through all those hoops if msvcrt is available in source?

Comment: @SergeyA This is the method I am used to using for this kind of thing.