# How to create instance-able custom clock with epoch set at runtime

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

My question is similar to this one ([How to create a custom clock for use in std::chrono functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533156/how-to-create-a-custom-clock-for-use-in-stdchrono-functions)) but with two minor differences:

1. The epoch isn't known until runtime
2. There could potentially be multiple instances of the clock, each with their own epoch

The use case I'm thinking of is for video stream time.  i.e. each frame in a video stream has a timestamp (pts, presentation time stamp) relative to the timestamp of the first frame. There could be multiple video streams, each with their own stream start time.

I think the epoch not being known until runtime is easy enough, just add a `set_epoch` function. however I'm not sure how it would be instanced where the `now()` function is static (which I would assume would require `set_epoch` to be static.)

So far I've just handled this by making the timestamp a `duration` instead of a `time_point` but that seems to be kind of an abuse of the types. It also  Is that the best solution or is there a better way? I guess maybe a broader question is, is it better to use a `time_point` or a `duration` type for a timestamp? A `time_point` seems the natural fit, but that means you'd have to truck around the clock definition.  A `duration` doesn't seem to fit the intended definition, but decouples it from the `clock` definition.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I think you're saying:  I need a stateful chrono::clock.  Right?

The epoch has to be a run-time data member of the clock.  And that doesn't really meet the [Cpp17Clock requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.req).

It turns out that the C++20 type `std::chrono::local_t` is also a clock that doesn't meet the [Cpp17Clock requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.req):

```
// [time.clock.local], local time
struct local_t {};
```

Convenience link: http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.local

> The family of time points denoted by `local_­time<Duration>` are based
> on the pseudo clock `local_­t`. `local_­t` has no member `now()` and
> thus does not meet the clock requirements.

[P2212](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2212r2.html) was written to address clocks that don't meet the [Cpp17Clock requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.req).  It turns out that one can create `time_point`s based on such clocks without any problem.  [The only thing you can't do with such clocks](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.req.paramname#1.sentence-3) is call algorithms that require the [Cpp17Clock requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.req).  For example `std::this_thread::sleep_until`.

But if you don't want to call `sleep_until` with a `MyCuriousClock::time_point`, then no harm, no foul.  If the standard can create a clock (`std::chrono::local_t`) that doesn't meet the [Cpp17Clock requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.req), then so can you — as long as you understand its limitations.

Comment: What about a clock whose native tick size (clock::rep) isn't known until run time? Is it possible to create one? (This is the case internally on Windows, where `KUSER_SHARED_DATA::TickCountMultiplier` is a runtime value.)

Comment: For a runtime tick one has to decide on a compile-time tick and then at runtime convert the runtime tick to the compile-time tick when returning from `now()`.  If you have a common runtime tick value, you can optimize at compile-time for the case when the conversion is 1-to-1.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem there is that the nice thing about using the exact runtime tick is that timestamping becomes literally 1 instruction (just reading the memory location), making it cheap enough to sprinkle in basically *anywhere* in code. Using any other tick will incur a performance hit on timestamping. The common case may not be too bad (just an extra branch) but then other cases will be more severe (multiply/divide). I have to wonder if there's really no way (even hacky) to support this in a mostly-standard-compliant manner? Especially given the new `clock_time_conversion` etc.

Comment: Delay the conversion to a chrono time_point/duration until you want to have more human-friendly units such as for display.

Comment: at that point I'm just designing my own custom clock interface though, right? Which is fine, I can do that, but the point was to make something standard compliant. I do see there's no way to do that though, thanks anyway.

Comment: For anyone wondering: the real solution here is to avoid the `TickCount` members entirely and just use `InterruptTime`. It's more accurate and it's always in units of 100ns. And it's what `QueryInterruptTime` uses.